# Laravel: Polymorphic relation without owning model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I will use the example of the laravel docs in order to explain my problem:

Imagine we want to store photos for staff members and for products. But also we want to store photos submitted by guests (so there is no record in our database for guests). We will need the following tables/models:

**staff**(id, name)

**products**(id, price)

**photos**(id, path, imageable_id, imageable_type)

I know that all the photos belonging to staff will have imageable_type = 'staff' and imageable_id = staff_id. The same applies for the photos of products but with imageable_type = 'products' and imageable_id = product_id.

Can I store the photos belonging to guests with imageable_id = NULL and imageable_id = NULL without breaking any convention / causing problems? Is this the right way of doing it?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Create a Guest model with only one row and create a polymorphic relation with it. then you can just fetch the guest photos

Comment: I thought about this option but is the Guest model really required?

Comment: Imho it's better to have one model then relate that to it than having a bunch of null values on your table. Don't get me wrong, there's nothing against having null values, it's just if you create a simple guest model you know that everything will work just fine

Comment: And with Fabio's suggestion, you can also put `NOT NULL` constraints for the `id` and `type` of the photos, which is always a good convention rule, when you deal with relations between entities, imo.

Comment: Thanks @FabioAntunes and Milkncookiez. I agree with both of you. I will create a Guest model because it looks like the best approach. Thanks guys!